# Qué podría estar fallando en esta consulta? A veces no se insertan los datos

Tags: mysql, pdo

Tengo cierto servicio funcionando hace 5 meses aprox, tiene alrededor de 30 usuarios activos. El punto es que en tres ocasiones durante este tiempo, 3 usuarios han presentado cierto problema relacionado con esta tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo apunta a que es esta consulta la que a veces, muy rara vez falla, ocasionando que simplemente no se inserten los datos:

```
$insup=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO `miTabla`(`id`,`puesto`, `codigos`) SELECT :id, `puesto`+1, :peticion FROM `miTabla` ORDER BY `puesto` DESC LIMIT 1 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id`=:id, `puesto`=(SELECT `puesto`+1 FROM `miTabla` ORDER BY `puesto` DESC LIMIT 1), `codigos`=:peticion;");
$insup->bindValue(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$insup->bindValue(':peticion',$peticion,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insup->execute();
```

Creo que la consulta está bien, pero tal vez no es eficiente o por algún motivo es propensa a errores. La construí hace aproximadamente 2 años, por lo que no recuerdo exactamente por qué quedó tan engorrosa. Pero se puede apreciar que cada vez que inserto un dato, aumento en +1 el índice de la columna "puesto".

Hace ya bastante tiempo que no me vuelven a reportar el error, pero necesito asegurarme de que no siga ocurriendo.

Entonces, si en un 99.9% de las veces funciona bien, ¿qué podría estar ocasionando que falle? Tiene que ver con esta consulta o podría ser algún otro factor externo como la velocidad de conexión de Internet de mis usuarios?

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez tu problema sea el `'puesto'+1`, ya que si 2 usuarios diferentes hacen una inserción al mismo tiempo, estos trataran de colocar el mismo valor en ese campo y producirá un error. Te recomendaría utilizar `AUTO_INCREMENT` en ese campo, no solo sirve para claves primarias, puedes ponerla en cualquier campo numérico que desees que se incremente con cada inserción.

**En codigo:**

Cambia el `'puesto'+1` por `'puesto'` en tu consulta de inserción y has esta modificación a tu tabla:

```
ALTER TABLE `mitabla`
MODIFY COLUMN `puesto` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT AFTER `id`;
```

y con eso vas a dejar de tener fallas, espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: lo intentaré, creo que intenté eso en un pasado pero hubo algo que lo impedía.